# How to link to the table of contents on every page?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, hyperref

How can I put a link back to the table of contents on every page (I guess the page number would be best place to add the link)?  I've tried searching, but didn't find anything and I'm not good enough with LaTeX to do it myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you know that with the `hyperref` package is easy make  linked `\ref`erences to sections or pages (with `\pageref`). The tricky part is  label the ToC, as you cannot place it just after sectioning command like `\section{foo}\label{foo}`. The solution is:

```
\tableofcontents\label{retoc} % well, really not very tricky ...
```

And then, use \hyperref[label]{text} elsewhere if you want other that link the section number ot the page numeber of the TOC. So can add some like this in your headers or footers:

```
\hyperref[retoc]{Page \thepage}
```

Alternatively to `\label`, you can use also `\hypertarget`. The problem here is that here are are a second argument (the text to show)  and only can be before the ToC, after the ToC, or be the ToC. But mark as target the whole ToC, that could have several pages is tricky (now really). To avoid the indigestion of `\hypertarget`, seem that one can protect it, at least in this example, and then make the link with `\hyperlink` in the header or footer. MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Foo}
\author{Foo}
\date{}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ \fancyhf{}  \fancyfoot[C]{ --- \hyperlink{toc}{\thepage} --- }}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\rhead{ \hyperlink{toc}{Page \thepage}}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\renewcommand\contentsname{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{Foo}}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo} \lipsum[1-3]
\section{Foo} \lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Foo} \lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Foo} \lipsum[1-3]
\section{Foo} \lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Foo} \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you get rid of the line on which the "Page $PAGENUMBER" rests (or at least put the number consistently on top, and not int chapter beginnings at the bottom)?  I actually kinda like the default look?  (Thanks a lot btw :) )

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` The fancyhdr manual have many examples of how customize every aspect of header and footers. Check it out.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!!